# when running sonar from jenkins Fail to retrieve SCM info Reason: The git blame command failed

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

Please help/guide me
I have:

1. configured sonar, jenkins and git all on my laptop.
2. integrated sonar with jenkins for auto builds.
3. added SCM activity plugin 1.8 to sonar 4.5.5 LTS.
4. added git path to environment variables.

**If i run sonar runner from cmd then SCM activity plugin works and it also shows SCM data in sonar. However if i run builds from jenkins it gives me this error:**

> 17:41:46.989 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor... 17:41:46.989 INFO  -
>   Trying to guess scm provider from project layout... 17:41:46.989 INFO 
>   - Found SCM type: git 17:41:46.993 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252... 17:41:47.033 INFO  -
>   Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Class1.cs 17:41:47.033 INFO  - Retrieve SCM
>   info for D:\GIT PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial
>   project\sample proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   17:41:47.033 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs 17:41:47.037
>   INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Program.cs 17:41:47.142 WARN  - Fail to
>   retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Class1.cs. Reason: The git blame command
>   failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.142 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Class1.cs 17:41:47.166 WARN  - Fail to
>   retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.170 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs 17:41:47.174
>   WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.174 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Program.cs 17:41:47.178 WARN  - Fail to
>   retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Program.cs. Reason: The git blame command
>   failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.178 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs 17:41:47.247 WARN
>   - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Class1.cs. Reason: The git blame command
>   failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.251 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\ExtendedOperations\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.251 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Form1.Designer.cs
>   17:41:47.251 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Form1.cs 17:41:47.283 WARN 
>   - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Program.cs. Reason: The git blame command
>   failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.283 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\InstallUtility.cs
>   17:41:47.299 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Form1.Designer.cs. Reason:
>   The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.299 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Program.cs 17:41:47.311 WARN
>   - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\Initialproj\initial project\sample proj\TFS
>   initial proj\initial project\sample
>   proj\C#\SimpleCalculator3\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.311 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   17:41:47.335 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Form1.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.335 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs
>   17:41:47.359 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\InstallUtility.cs. Reason:
>   The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.359 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs
>   17:41:47.383 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Program.cs. Reason: The git
>   blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.383 INFO  - Retrieve SCM info for D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\ScriptUtility.cs
>   17:41:47.403 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.
>   Reason: The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.403 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs.
>   Reason: The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.419 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs.
>   Reason: The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.427 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: D:\GIT
>   PROJECT\ExecuteSQLScript\ScriptTool\Test1\ScriptUtility.cs. Reason:
>   The git blame command failed. 'git' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 17:41:47.431 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding
>   windows-1252 done: 434 ms

Comment: Is git installed on your machine?

Comment: @DavidRACODON-QAConsultant yes, for sure; i've mentioned it in points.

Comment: My bad... In the Jenkins job, if you add a build step to execute a command such as 'git clone xxx', does it work?

Comment: It should work as i have configured build to fetch from github before processing msbuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess two things

- Jenkins is not running under your user account
- %PATH% of the user that is running Jenkins does not include Git

I believe this could be the case even if you can successfully add (and run!) a Git checkout to a Jenkins job, depending on how your Jenkins tools are set up.

Comment: @Himanshu I can't help you configure %PATH% directly. But where is Git installed? Is it in one of the "normal" places to have applications?

Comment: Git is installed in C:\Program Files\Git and i have added C:\Program Files\Git;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin in PATH variable in environment variables.

Comment: OP, was your problem solved by the answer above which was accepted?

I face a similar situation but on linux, and this does not solve it, since I have already taken care of the two bullet points provided by @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, also both my jenkins and sonar are started with sudo, and still no luck. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now, thanks for your support. In services i configured Jenkins and Sonar to run as Administrator. Now jenkins is doing what it was supposed to so without errors.